# How do I use the postgres crate to receive table modification events from PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql, rust

I have a Rust process dealing with a PostgreSQL database. This process communicates with a server process to pass on the details using MPSC channels. I am stuck on how to listen for and process events for table modification.

I tried using tokio-postgres but it seems there is [an issue](https://users.rust-lang.org/t/tokio-postgres-0-3-0-as-dependency-introduces-error-failed-to-resolve-use-of-undeclared-type-or-module-connecterror/29584/2) with it on Windows.

Comment: This question is rather broad and somewhat unclear. You do not specify what exactly you want to do on the database side, nor what you want to do on the application side. Please break this down into steps, and ask more specific questions, or go to a different platform for a more open-ended discussion (e.g. Reddit). My impression is that you first need to clarify what exactly you want the database to do. There are no "table modification events" per se in Postgres. You can write a trigger that notifies a channel, but in any case you should write the SQL first before thinking about Rust.

Answer (score 0):

Listening for events on specific channel for PostgreSQL goes as below :-

```
// Establish connection with database.
let url = "postgresql://root:root1234@127.0.01/test";
let conn = Connection::connect(url, TlsMode::None).unwrap();

// Listen for events on channel 'myevent'.
conn.execute("LISTEN myevent", &[]).expect("Could not send LISTEN");
let notifications = conn.notifications();
let mut it = notifications.blocking_iter();

println!("Waiting for notifications...");
loop {
    let a = it.next();
    match a {
        Ok(Some(b)) => {
            println!("{:?}", b);
        },
        Err(e) => println!("Got error {:?}", e),
        _ => panic!("Unexpected operation!!!")
    }
}
```